# Messaging.InboundEmailHandler email test class not covering whole class

Tags: code-coverage, apex-email-service

Please help cover bold lines dont know why email.plainTextBody.length() >=255 is not covering

**if(email.plainTextBody!=null && email.plainTextBody.length() >=255) {

bodyString= email.plainTextBody.split('\n', 0);
body = bodyString[0]; comment = bodyString[1];  uName = bodyString[2];
uString = uName.replaceAll(regex, ''); uniqueContractNo = uString.replaceAll( '\s+', '');**

```
global class frEmailServiceClass implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
    string body='', fromEmailId='';
        list<string> approvalString = new list<string>{'APPROVE', 'APPROVED', 'YES'};
        list<string> rejectionString = new list<string>{'REJECT', 'REJECTED', 'NO'};
        string[] bodyString;
        string comment;
        string uniqueContractNo;
        string subj =email.subject;
        string regex = '[a-zA-Z]{1,}|\\:';
        string cString = subj.replaceAll(regex, '');
        string cName = cString.replaceAll( '\\s+', '');
        string uName;
        string uString;
        try{
        **if(email.plainTextBody!=null && email.plainTextBody.length() >=255) {  
        bodyString= email.plainTextBody.split('\n', 0);
        body = bodyString[0]; comment = bodyString[1];  uName = bodyString[2];
        uString = uName.replaceAll(regex, ''); uniqueContractNo = uString.replaceAll( '\\s+', '');**
                                                                            
        }
                fromEmailId = email.fromAddress;   
        Contract_management__c   contractQuery = new Contract_management__c();
            if(cName!=null){
            system.debug(cName);
        contractQuery = [select id,name,Status__c,Comments__c,Unique_Contract_Number__c,owner.email,Legal_Person_Email__c,Send_Email_To_Legal__c from Contract_management__c where name=:cName and Legal_Person_Email__c=:fromEmailId limit 1];
            }
        
        **for(string a:approvalString){            
        if(body.contains(a) && contractQuery!=null){ contractQuery.Status__c= 'Legal Approved';
            contractQuery.Send_Email_To_Legal__c=false;  contractQuery.Comments__c=comment;
            contractQuery.Unique_Contract_Number__c=uniqueContractNo;
            }                   
        }
        
        for(string r:rejectionString){
        if(body.contains(r) && contractQuery!=null){ contractQuery.Status__c= 'Legal Rejected';
            contractQuery.Send_Email_To_Legal__c=false; contractQuery.Comments__c=comment;  
            contractQuery.Unique_Contract_Number__c=uniqueContractNo;
            }                   
        }
        
        
        update contractQuery;**
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('Line No: '+ex.getLineNumber()+' Message: '+ex.getMessage()+' Cause: '+ex.getCause());
        }
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
            return result;
    }
}
```

Test class method

```
@isTest 
    static void testContractEmailServiceMethod(){
        string cid;
        Contract_management__c queryC = [select id,name,Legal_Person_Email__c,Customer_Account__c,Contact__c,Contract_Type__c,Contract_Start_Date__c,Contract_End_Date__c,Status__c from Contract_management__c limit 1 ];
        cid=queryC.name;
    list<string> approvalString = new list<string>();
    Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail() ;
    Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();
    
    FREmailServiceClass contractClassObj = new FREmailServiceClass();
    
    email.plainTextBody = 'APPROVED\n ok\n 0090';
    email.fromAddress ='test@u.com';
    email.subject = cid;
    
    
    contractClassObj.handleInboundEmail(email, envelope);
}
```

Comment: The length of your `email.plainTextBody` is 67 characters i.e "APPROVED\n ok\n 0090". Your conditional check will only run the code block when `plainTextBody` is greater than or equal to 255 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your IF condition is failing because the length of your email.plainTextBody is less than 255.
If you debug "email.plainTextBody.length()" you will get to know that the lenght is < (less than) 255.

[image]